# no viable alternative at input in

Tags: sql, databricks

I have an error:

> no viable alternative at input '(CASE WHEN (fdse.`eventaction` IN 'zoom image''(line 2, pos 34)

In the code

```
 %sql
 SELECT
 (CASE WHEN (fdse.`eventaction` IN 'zoom image') THEN SUM(CAST(fdse.`totalevents` AS BIGINT)) 
 END) AS `zoom`
 FROM GA_FAVORITES_DIGITAL_STYLIST_EVENTS AS fdse
 INNER JOIN GA_FAVORITES_SESSIONS AS fs
 ON fdse.uniquesessionid = fs.uniquesessionid
 AND fdse.trans_date = fs.trans_date
 where fs.trans_date >= date_add(current_date,-10)
 LIMIT 10
```

But usually, this error comes up when some character is missing or in the wrong place. I really cannot get where is the problem, checked several times.

Comment: I think this `IN 'zoom image'` should be `IN ('zoom image')` or use `=` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot! Done that, but now having another error Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'fdse.`eventaction`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(CASE WHEN (fdse.`eventaction` = 'zoom image') THEN sum(CAST(fdse.`totalevents` AS BIGINT)) END AS `CASE WHEN (eventaction = zoom image) THEN sum(CAST(totalevents AS BIGINT)) END`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'fdse.`eventaction`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
GlobalLimit 10. Do you have any ideas why? :(

Comment: Check the query on the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf868c588fd41b6ba7f589256ac92a7b) . I changed the case condition and added an group by clause. When doing aggregation function in most cases you have to  use group by. In your case if you need total sum, there is no need for group by. But I saw using limit , so you need sum for particular groups. Try and let me know

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your help. I see that the query in fiddle is the same as mine. Maybe the link is different?

Comment: Yeah, I pasted the wrong link, try https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c54f0b1bfcd19e841e3c388a0e6be68a